# Change background color of Material Ui datepicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

I want to change the background color of my material ui datepicker modal

import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core";

```
const materialTheme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiPickersToolbar: {
            toolbar: {
                backgroundColor: 'red',
            },
        },
        MuiPickersDay: {
            day: {
                color: 'black',

            },
            daySelected: {
                backgroundColor: '#33abb6',
            },
            dayDisabled: {
                color: '#ccc',
            },
            current: {
                color: 'red',
            },
        },
        MuiPickersModal: {
            dialogAction: {
                color: '#33abb6',
            },
        },
    },
});


export default materialTheme
```

In the above code i was able to change colors of date and few others but not the total background color

Are there any documentation from which i can get these class names or any other option

Answer (score 2):

Try in CSS:

```
.MuiPaper-root {
  background-color: #eaea87;
}
```

Comment: i wanted a solution for jss

Answer (score 1):

In recent version of MUI (v5.3.1) I resolved this issue by adding `sx={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}` to `TextField` in `renderInput` prop as below:

```js
<MobileDatePicker
  label="Date"
  value={date}
  onChange={(newValue) => {
  setDate(newValue);
  }}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      sx={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}
      fullWidth
      {...params}
    />
  )}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `createTheme` to provide component overrides ([see docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/#default-props)):

```js
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    // Name of the component
    MuiInputBase: {
      styleOverrides: {
        // Name of the slot
        root: {
          // Some CSS
          backgroundColor: "white",
          // add variant styles like so
          "&.Mui-disabled": {
            "backgroundColor": "#cccccc"
          }
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

You can see the name of the component to use by inspect element and looking at the class names, and you can find the slots in the component definition, [e.g. this is the slots for the `MuiInput` component](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-material/src/Input/Input.js#L19).

Also see [this source on combining class names to target `disabled`, `hover`, `active` etc](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/#2-reusable-component).

Answer (score -2):

MuiPickers is using Dialog Material Ui, so override all dialog component that be used in this pickers. I'm not sure with this solution below. You can try this, hope it's worked.

```
   const materialTheme = createMuiTheme({
        overrides: {
            MuiPickersToolbar: {
                toolbar: {
                    backgroundColor: 'red',
                },
            },
            MuiPickersDay: {
                day: {
                    color: 'black',
    
                },
                daySelected: {
                    backgroundColor: '#33abb6',
                },
                dayDisabled: {
                    color: '#ccc',
                },
                current: {
                    color: 'red',
                },
            },
            MuiPickersModal: {
                dialogAction: {
                    color: '#33abb6', 
                    backgroundColor: 'YOUR HEX HERE',
                },
            },
        },
    });
```

I think the good way is send style in DialogProps

> https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/DateTimePicker (section modal wrapper)

so then you can override all dialog modal.